# How to generate a pseudopotential for a cation/anion?

Tags: density-functional-theory, pseudopotentials

Many DFT codes use pseudopotentials to represent the electron-ion interaction (as do most plane-wave codes and in contrast to so-called "all-electron" programs).

There are several [resources](https://www.nnin.org/search/node/pseudopotential) on the web to generate pseudopotentials in different formats and for different DFT codes. One of them is the program [ATOM](http://bohr.inesc-mn.pt/~jlm/pseudo.html). Bellow is an example ot the ATOM input file for carbon.

```
       pg                  -- file generated from C ps file
        tm2
    C   ca 
     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000     0.000
    1    4
    2    0     2.000     0.000    #2s
    2    1     2.000     0.000    #2p
    3    2     0.000     0.000    #3d
    4    3     0.000     0.000    #4f
   1.56000   1.56000   1.56000   1.56000   0.00000   0.00000

#23456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890      Ruler
```

My question is: how to generate a pseudopotential for a cation/anion?

Comment: I don't really know how to do it, but wouldn't one expect the net charge to be irrelevant to represent the inner core of an atom?

Answer (score 6):

Why would you want to generate a pseudopotential for a cation/anion? The pseudopotential is only for the inner core electrons. The only case where you'd want to do this is when the charge state of the system is so extreme that the inner shells are disturbed as well. (Also note that anions are ill-described by DFT so setting up an anion pseudopotential would be problematic.)

Comment: I asked the same thing. But I had a paper where one of the referees insist that as I used a single atom, it must be in ionic state, so, I have to generate a new pseudopotential to take into account the charge diference.

Comment: If you only have a single atom, you don't need pseudopotentials; you can run a much more accurate calculation directly with an atomic approach...

Comment: There are 121 atoms. A nanotube and the atom that is put near it.

Comment: Okay, then the reviewer's demand really doesn't make any sense! :D